# In a javascript OR statements, which value is used if both values are defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following snippet:

```
var prevPageWrap = data.prevPage.jqmData("wrapper"),
    pageBackBtn = page.closest('div:jqmData(wrapper="true")').jqmData("usebackbtn"),
    useBackBtn =  pageBackBtn || o.useBackBtn;

if ( useBackBtn && !prevPageWrap ){
    self.crumble(event, data, page );
    }
```

My problem is `useBackBtn`. Im setting `usebackbtn` to false in my HTML element like so:

```
<div data-role="page" id="landing" data-wrapper="true" data-scrollmode="overthrow" data-usebackbtn="false">

</div>
```

which I'm also able to retrieve.

Still

```
useBackBtn =  pageBackBtn || o.useBackBtn;
```

is set to true, although `pageBackBtn` is false.

**Question**:
If the first "option" is false and the second option is true, what will be the value of `useBackBtn` = What supercedes what? Is there a shorthand syntax way to say "if the first option is defined, take it, otherwise try the 2nd option?"

Comment: You need to be aware that you are probably getting the string 'false' which evaluates to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the first "option" is false and the second option is true, what will be the value of `useBackBtn =` What supercedes what?

The second option.

`a || b` evaluates as `a` if `a` is a true value, otherwise it evaluates as `b`.

> Is there a shorthand syntax way to say "if the first option is defined, take it, otherwise try the 2nd option?"

Use a ternary operator.

```
var a, b, result;
a = 0;
b = 1;
result = typeof a !== "undefined" ? a : b
alert(result)
```

Comment: Technically, `||` is the lazy logical or operator in JavaScript.  It only evaluates the second operand if it has to, because the first argument is falsy.  Note that I don't say `false` because JavaScript has some quite unusual notions of truthiness or falsiness, where empty string, `null`, and `0`, as well as false are all falsy.   This wierdness leads to the convention in JavaScript of `x || y` meaning use x as a default, and y if x isn't there.  In my opinion, poor language design, but that is the way it is.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: FWIW, these values are "falsy" in other languages as well. The "lazy" evaluation of the `OR` operator is called short-circuit evaluation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation.

Comment: @Quentin: won't jslint complain for using `typeof a !== "undefined"` vs `a === undefined`?

Comment: @FelixKling That may be true, but JavaScript is the only one I am personally aware of enough to have it sink in to my brain.  And other languages doing it doesn't mean it is a good idea :-)   I would guess these are mostly languages with dynamic typing, but JavaScript is the only dynamically typed language I have used since LISP in the 80s.  And I know the term short circuit evaluation, and lazy evaluation is a synonym in context. :-)

Comment: @frequent JSLINT complains about a lot of things, but you are right, this is one of its warnings, and often one well worth paying attention to as it is the source of unexpected and hard to see bugs.

Comment: Why would JSLint complain about that?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: I agree. What I wanted to say with this is that it seems to be less weird if you are used to other languages as well. It's just a matter of perspective. I would be utterly confused if `if(0)` would evaluate to `true` ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I still bear the scars of C where we used small ints for booleans, and chars, ints, booleans, and pointers were practically indistinguishable.   I like my types firmly knowing what they are--which is not to say I don't love dynamic typing (oh, I do, I do), I just want my dynamic types to know well who they are. :-)  I agree `if (0)` should not be true, but I think it should be an error.

Comment: @frequent — Yes, it will, but since it is possible for code to overwrite `undefined`, I'll disagree with Crockford on that particular linting rule.

Comment: I went through a phase where I used `void 0` instead of `undefined`, as in `a === void 0` - the `void` operator returns `undefined`, but avoids the problem of other code overwriting the _name_ `undefined` and is fewer characters to type, too. But I stopped because I was tired of being stared at. @SAJ14SAJ: JavaScript dynamic types do know who they are - the actual value is always one type or another: this is a different issue to whether the language should have a truthy/falsy concept. (Technicalities aside, I just like the words "truthy" and "falsy" - I like saying them. Falsy, falsy, falsy.)